# MultiSelectList does not highlight previously selected items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, listbox

In a ASP.NET MVC (Razor) project, I'm using a `ListBox` with Multi Select option in a Edit View,

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        string selectedValues = post.Tags; //This contains Selected values list (Eg: "AA,BB")
        ViewBag.Tagslist = GetTags(selectedValues.Split(','));
        return View(post);
    }

    private MultiSelectList GetTags(string[] selectedValues)
    {
        var tagsQuery = from d in db.Tags
                        orderby d.Name
                        select d;
        return new MultiSelectList(tagsQuery, "Name", "Name", selectedValues);

    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBox("Tags", ViewBag.Tagslist as MultiSelectList)
    </div>
```

This loads the items (Tag List) in to `ListBox`, but does not highlight the items in the `Selected Values` list.

How to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `Post` class (to which your view is strongly typed) has a property called `Tags`. You also use `Tags` as first argument of the `ListBox` helper. This means that the helper will look into this property first and ignore the selected values you passed to the `MultiSelectList`. So the correct way to set a selected value is the following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Tagslist = GetTags();
    return View(post);
}

private MultiSelectList GetTags()
{
    var tagsQuery = from d in db.Tags
                    orderby d.Name
                    select d;
    return new MultiSelectList(tagsQuery, "Name", "Name");

}
```

and in the view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Tags, ViewBag.Tagslist as MultiSelectList)
</div>
```

---

And here's a full example that should illustrate:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var post = new Post
        {
            Tags = new[] { "AA", "BB" }
        };
        var allTags = new[]
        {
            new { Name = "AA" }, new { Name = "BB" }, new { Name = "CC" },
        };
        ViewBag.Tagslist = new MultiSelectList(allTags, "Name", "Name");
        return View(post);
    }
}
```

Also I would recommend you using view models instead of passing your domain entities to the view. So in your `PostViewModel` you will have a property called `AllTags` of type `MultiSelectList`. This way you will be able to get rid of the weak typed `ViewBag`.

Comment: One thing, In your full example `Tags` is an array, but in my case its a string value.

Comment: Oh, that's your problem and explains why you don't get any selected value. The `ListBox` helper expects as first argument a property that is of type collection. If you don't have such property you have 2 possibilities: 1. use view models as I suggested 2. Use some dummy name property that doesn't exist in your Post model and then the selectedValues should work (or not -> I haven't tested it so cannot confirm 100% -> I would use view models anyways).