# MultiSelectList does not highlight items in the selectedValues list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, listbox, viewmodel

In a ASP.NET MVC (Razor) project, I'm using a ListBox with Multi Select option in a Edit View, there was a problem in highlighting the previously selected items by using `selectedValues` in `MultiSelectList`, so I asked a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077032/multiselectlist-does-not-highlight-previously-selected-items) previously. According to the answers given for that question I decided to use a ViewModel (with AutoMapper) for passing the data to the View, without using the `ViewBag`, but still I have the same problem.. It does not select the items given in the `selectedValues` list

this is my new code

**MODELS**

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Tags { get; set; }

}

public class PostEditViewModel
{
    private DocLibraryContext db = new DocLibraryContext();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..
    public MultiSelectList TagsList { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        PostEditViewModel postEditViewModel = Mapper.Map<Post, PostEditViewModel>(post);

        var tagsQuery = from d in db.Tags
                        orderby d.Name
                        select d;
        postEditViewModel.TagsList = new MultiSelectList(tagsQuery, "Id", "Name", post.Tags.Split(','));

        return View(postEditViewModel);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Tags, Model.TagsList as MultiSelectList)
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help....

---

**UPDATE 1 :**

changed controller to

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        PostEditViewModel postEditViewModel = Mapper.Map<Post, PostEditViewModel>(post);

        var tagsQuery = from d in db.Tags
                        orderby d.Name
                        select d;

        var selectedIds = post.Tags.Split(',').Select(n => tagsQuery.First(t => t.Name == n));
        postEditViewModel.TagsList = new MultiSelectList(tagsQuery, "Id", "Name", selectedIds);

        return View(postEditViewModel);
    }
```

but I get the same results.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried changing code (as in [this](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm) tutorial), which worked, But I need to use previous method..

**MODELS**

```
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList TagsList { get; set; }

    public PostEditViewModel(Post post)
    {
        Post = post;
        var tagsQuery = from d in db.Tags
                        orderby d.Name
                        select d;
        TagsList = new MultiSelectList(tagsQuery, "Name", "Name", post.Tags.Split(','));
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        return View(new PostEditViewModel(post));
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBox("Tags", Model.TagsList as MultiSelectList)
</div>
```

What makes the difference...??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the construction of your `MultiSelectList`:

```
new MultiSelectList(tagsQuery, "Id", "Name", post.Tags.Split(','));
```

You are specifying that the values for the elements will be taken from each tag's `Id` property, but then for the actual selected values you are passing in an array of strings which presumably corresponds to the `Name`s of the tags. It doesn't matter that you also specify `Name` to be the property from which the display text will be determined; the `selectedValues` parameter matches against values, not display text.

To fix this, project each tag name into its corresponding `Id`:

```
var selectedIds = post.Tags.Split(',').Select(n => tagsQuery.First(t => t.Name == n).Id);
new MultiSelectList(tagsQuery, "Id", "Name", selectedIds);
```

**Update:**

Oops, there was a mistake in the code above.

I edited the answer to add a required `.Id` at the end of the `selectedIds` initialization -- the previous version was selecting tags, not ids (and of course they were comparing unequal, apples and oranges).

Comment: @Nalaka526: Post the exact code that didn't work as an update to the question please.

Comment: @Nalaka526: Thanks, that helped realize I had make a small but critical omission :) Please have a look again.

Comment: @Nalaka526: Just saw your second update. The difference is what I mentioned above: if you say that values are going to be coming from `Tag.Name`, that's what you also have to pass for `selectedValues`. The same for `Tag.Id`.

Comment: Thank you very much  for the support given & Sorry for bothering you, In the View I get the `MultiSelectView` with the value with `selected=true`, but it is not selected in the List box, any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used my own extention method to generate the html and problem solved

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ListBoxMultiSelectFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
        object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return ListBoxMultiSelectFor(helper, expression, selectList, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString ListBoxMultiSelectFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
        IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        TagBuilder selectTag = new TagBuilder("select");
        selectTag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        selectTag.MergeAttribute("id", name, true);
        selectTag.MergeAttribute("name", name, true);
        foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList)
        {
            TagBuilder optionTag = new TagBuilder("option");
            optionTag.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value);
            if (item.Selected) optionTag.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");
            optionTag.InnerHtml = item.Text;
            selectTag.InnerHtml += optionTag.ToString();
        }

        return  new MvcHtmlString(selectTag.ToString());
    }
```